# How to add buttons on sublime text 2?

Tags: button, uibutton, sublimetext2

I want to add many function buttons to the top bar menu in the Sublime Text 2. How do I do this?
Buttons that I need to add:

- Save
- Save as
- Open
- Open as

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add menu entries, but it is not possible to add UI buttons. That being said, you may be able to mimic the behavior you want by creating Menu entries with a command at the top level, rather than having nested entries. To do this, create a `Main.sublime-menu` file in your `Packages/User` Folder. Insert the following into the file.

```
[
    {
        "caption": "Save",
        "command": "save"
    },
    {
        "caption": "Save As",
        "command": "prompt_save_as"
    },
    {
        "caption": "Open File",
        "command": "prompt_open_file"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed possible. I know the solution for ST3, and am not sure if it will work with ST2, yet give it a shot:

Linux solution. Try to find these files on windows if that's what you are using

Step 1.
Go to `/opt/sublime_text/Packages`

Step 2.
Copy the file `Default.sublime-package` somewhere.... (ex. `Desktop`)

Step 3.
Extract the contents somewhere (ex. `Desktop/aFolder`)

Step 4. Go to the extracted folder and copy `Main.sublime-menu`

Step 5. Paste it into `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Default`

NOTE: Create the `Default` folder if it doesn't already exist

Step 6. Edit `Main.sublime-menu` to your liking

Comment: Works in windows, too.